# Issue on Uploading Two SOE to ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, server-object-extension

I need to upload two [REST SOE](https://github.com/nicogis/Geometric-Network-Utility-SOE) to ArcGIS Server. They are technically same and I just copied second one from the first and renamed the project and built it but when I tried to upload the second SOE ArcGIS server Complained that

[image]

so I tried to change some configurations at second SOE as

1- in [Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs](https://github.com/nicogis/Geometric-Network-Utility-SOE/blob/master/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs) I changed

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("GeometricNetworkUtility")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Geometric Network Utility")]

[assembly: AddInPackage("ArcGIS.Soe.Rest.GeometricNetworkUtilitybyPhase", "f15446f6-4217-4c50-a970-078c0b64a20a",
    Author = " ",
    Company = " ",
    Description = "Geometric Network Utility",
    TargetProduct = "Server",
    TargetVersion = "10.4", 

    Version = "1.3")]
```

To

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("GeometricNetworkUtility2")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Geometric Network Utility 2")]

[assembly: AddInPackage("ArcGIS.Soe.Rest.GeometricNetworkUtility2", "f15446f6-4217-4c50-a970-078c0b64a20a",
    Author = " ",
    Company = " ",
    Description = "Geometric Network Utility 2",
    TargetProduct = "Server",
    TargetVersion = "10.4", 

    Version = "1.3")]
```

and in [GeometricNetworkUtility.cs](https://github.com/nicogis/Geometric-Network-Utility-SOE/blob/master/GeometricNetworkUtility.cs)  I changed the

```
Description = "Geometric Network Utility",
DisplayName = "Geometric Network Utility",
```

to

```
Description = "Geometric Network Utility 2",
DisplayName = "Geometric Network Utility 2",
```

but still after rebuilding the solution and uploading the new SOE I am getting the same error message. Can you please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: What benefit do you expect to see from creating identical services? Aliasing them differently doesn't change the fact that the class names are identical. You'd have to rename the class itself, but if the signatures are identical, there is no reason to do so. Please make sure the error message is in the question body *as text*, so the error is legible on all devices and searchable by others.